# how to extend Expiration date for test certificate

Tags: visual-studio, clickonce, publishing

In Visual studio click Once Publishing we use Test Certificate to sign Mainfest which Expire after one year.

how I can extent Expiration Date?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I renew my expired ClickOnce certificate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280472/how-can-i-renew-my-expired-clickonce-certificate)

Answer (score 1):

If you're after a quick solution, then you can "renew" your existing certificate and just give it a longer expiry date.

Cliff Stanford has cleaned up the Microsoft "workaround" and made it available as a simple command line exe - available here: http://may.be/renewcert/ - Nice work Cliff !

[How can I renew my expired ClickOnce certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4888638/1583653)