# ClickOnce application doesn't override old application on update (PublicKeyToken changed?)

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, clickonce, code-signing

I have inherited an ClickOnce application from a previous developer and I have a problem deploying it. When I build and publish the application and a user tries to update/reinstall from it's address it does not overwrite the old app, but installs another application. The update is installed as a new application under the name of `(Application Name)-1`.

From what I'm guessing it's an issue with the `PublicKeyToken` that is the id of the app. It differs between properly updating versions (from the old developer) and the ones I publish.

The application in question is signed with a code signing certificate from a CA (I've got the `.pfx`, `.cer` and `.pem` files) and once used a strong name key file, but I've been told that It's not used for some time now and the updates still worked without it (I have the `.snk` file).

Additionally the code signing certificate timed out recently and has been extended by a CA. I've got new `.pfx`, `.cer` and `.pem` files from this.

I'm trying to guess what might be the cause of this `PublicKeyToken` change (or is it event the cause of this issue). I have these possibilities:

1. I haven't copied some system certificate/setting from the previous developer
2. There was some issue with extending the code signing certificates
3. Something related to that strong name (`.snk`) file?

Currently I have no way to check if the `PublicKeyToken` is the same when published from the old developers machine using the new certificates. Will try that when possible.

So, can anyone please help me on how to continue to publish my application with the same PublicKeyToken as before?

Comment: Related: the second comment in http://stackoverflow.com/a/4888638/785171 - the answer itself is old and (hopefully) out of date, this and most answers point that this is fixed in .NET 3.5 (I'm using 4.5) and it should work (it doesn't).