# Extend a Sha256 Test Certificate for ClickOnce

Tags: certificate, clickonce, sha1, sha256, sha

First, I know there are a lot of posts about clickonce test certificates renewal on OF but this is not the core of the question.

I have an internal clickonce app signed with a Test Certificate that expired.
We now need to deploy a new version but we don't want to force everyone to reinstall our app and risk them to lose personnal settings.

I tried using [OceanAirdrop's ExtendClickOnceCertificate](https://github.com/OceanAirdrop/ExtendClickOnceCertificate) (a derivative from the original MS RenewCert application) but I always end up with a SHA1 certificate while the original one is SHA256. How can I get it (or any other renewal tool) to really make an extended clone of the original?

(The basic renewal problem was already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280472/how-can-i-renew-my-expired-clickonce-certificate). This question is about the renewal of a SHA256 certificate)

Answer (score 0):

I solve this issue by downloading ExtendClickOnceCertificate and then:

I made some changes in the Crypt.cs File to solve this issue.

First add this two struct:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct CRYPT_ALGORITHM_IDENTIFIER
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string pszObjId;
    public CRYPTOAPI_BLOB parameters;
}
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct CRYPTOAPI_BLOB
{
    public uint cbData;
    public IntPtr pbData;
}
```

Then, modify the CertCreateSelfSignCertificate function like this:

```
[DllImport("Crypt32.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
        internal static extern IntPtr CertCreateSelfSignCertificate(
           IntPtr providerHandle,
           ref CRYPT_DATA_BLOB subjectIssuerBlob,
           int flags,
           IntPtr pinfo,
           ref CRYPT_ALGORITHM_IDENTIFIER pSignatureAlgorithm,
            Native.SYSTEMTIME pStartTime,
            Native.SYSTEMTIME pEndTime,
           IntPtr extensions);
```

In Program.cs, before calling CertCreateSelfSignCertificate, add this:

```
Crypt.CRYPT_ALGORITHM_IDENTIFIER signatureAlgorithm = new Crypt.CRYPT_ALGORITHM_IDENTIFIER {
                    pszObjId = "1.2.840.113549.1.1.11"
                };
```

Finally, change the call to the CertCreateSelfSignCertificate to look like this:

```
hCertContext = Crypt.CertCreateSelfSignCertificate(hCPContext, ref certNameBlob, 0,Info,ref signatureAlgorithm, null, certExpireDate, IntPtr.Zero);
```

And that is all. Compile the solution and run the command. This worked for me.